# Set conditional request header if client ip is local

Tags: apache, header, conditional-statements

I'm trying to set a request header in Apache, the value of the header depends on the IP address of the client. If the IP address is local (private range) the value of the header should be "inside" else it should be "outside"

So far I have configured:

```
     RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
     RemoteIPInternalProxy 172.24.x.x
```

The value of X-Forwarded-For now has the clients IP address. The other part should be solvable with Apache If then Else Syntax but I have no idea how to check the value of X-Forwarded-For and compare it against all local/private IP ranges.

```
<If "????????'">
 RequestHeader set My-Header "inside"
</If>
<Else>
 RequestHeader set My-Header "outside"
</Else>
```

I'm running:

```
  Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
  Server built:   Aug  8 2019 11:41:18
```

Answer (score 1):

I manged to solve it myself, I can probably use an or statements to get rid of the Elsifs and write the entire condition in just one if but I like how this reads. If a better approach exists I'm still interested.

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy 172.24.x.x #Loadbalancer IP

<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '010.000.000.000/8'">
 RequestHeader set My-Header "inside"
</If>
<ElseIf "%{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '172.016.000.000/12'">
 RequestHeader set My-Header "inside"
</ElseIf>
<ElseIf "%{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '192.168.000.000/16'">
 RequestHeader set My-Header "inside"
</ElseIf>
<Else>
 RequestHeader set My-Header "outside"
</Else>
```

Comment: To simplify you can use -R option : 
<If -R '010.000.000.000/8'>

Comment: According to the [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/expr.html#unnop) `-R` is same as `%{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch x` but _more efficient_.